# How to make a list draggable with touch events? HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I want to make a list draggable. 
I understand that there're alot of plugins to get the effect but I want to achieve some kind of drag and drop function that changes positions of the list items with only javascript. And I've been searching for days without any success. I would like to use the touch events for touch devices. Where do I start?

```
<ul> 
    <li><h3>How</h3></li>
    <li><h3>To</h3></li>
    <li><h3>Drag</h3></li>
    <li><h3>and Drop</h3></li>
</ul>
```

I'm kinda new to javascript so I really appreciate any help!